# Account Name error on multiple Pivot Tables on different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, automation, pivot, pivot-table

I have 4 multiples workbooks and all workbooks contains multiple pivots with Common fields Account Name and Year.  I've written a code to change all Pivot at once on Account Name & Year but getting error on Account Name

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
            For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
                With pt
                    With .PivotFields("Account Name")
                        .ClearAllFilters
                        .CurrentPage = accountName ---- getting error on this line
                    End With
                    With .PivotFields("Year")
                        .CurrentPage = year
                    End With
                End With
                Next pt
```

Comment: What's the error? What's the value of accountName?